# Naive question on symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an incredibly naive question, yet which makes me doubt.

Is: $(A\bigtriangleup A^c)\cup A=A\bigtriangleup A^c$, where $\bigtriangleup$ denotes the symmetric difference?

I can prove yes, and no, so I am confused...

Comment: Start by proving that $A \Delta A^C = A \cup A^C$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the universal set in which this calculation is taking place. (Some such universal set is needed if you’re going to talk about complements.) Then

$$A\mathrel{\triangle}A^c=(A\setminus A^c)\cup(A^c\setminus A)=A\cup A^c=X\;.$$

Of course $X\cup B=X$ for each $B\subseteq X$, so in particular $X\cup A=X$. Thus,

$$(A\mathrel{\triangle}A^c)\cup A=X\cup A=X=A\mathrel{\triangle}A^c\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true.  Let us say we are talking about subsets of some set $X$.  Then for any $A\subseteq X$, $A\mathbin\triangle A^c=X$, and so $(A\mathbin\triangle A^c)\cup A=X\cup A=X$.  Indeed, $$A\mathbin\triangle A^c=(A^c\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap (A^c)^c)=A^c\cup (A\cap A)=A^c\cup A=X.$$